# Obtaining velocity in a given direction from velocity potential

Tags: fluid-dynamics, potential, vectors, fluid-statics

Considering that velocity potential $\phi$ can be defined, one can write the components of velocity $ \boldsymbol{u}$ (in 2D) as
$$u_x = {\partial \phi \over \partial x}, \ u_y = {\partial \phi \over \partial y}$$

Thus for any direction $\hat{n}$, one can say, the velocity $u_n$ in $\hat{n}$  direction is

$$u_n = \boldsymbol{u}\cdot\hat{n}$$

According to a text I'm reading, the velocity in $\hat{n}$ direction is given by $u_n = {\partial \phi \over \partial \hat{n}}$. I am lost in here, how can these two expressions be equal?

Comment: Do you understand that your symbol means $\frac{\partial }{\partial \hat n}= \hat n\cdot \nabla$ ?

Comment: I was not aware of it, can you please point out a reference for this. Thank you!

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative).